# Complicated nested request in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I have a collection with documents of this format:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51b1e27e31b1f4fe0700001b"),
        "proposals" : [
                {
                        "id" : 17,
                        "type" : "question",
                        "fr" : {nothing useful},
                        "en" : {nothing useful},
                        "vote_count" : 0,
                        "validate" : 0,
                        "username" : "username",
                        "voters" : [ ],
                        "creationDate" : ISODate("2013-07-25T08:32:40.328Z")
                }, 
                {other proposals of the same type}
         ]
},
{same format}
```

I'm trying to update the proposal matched by an ID that I receive, in the right parent. I have found [a request on the Mongo cookbook](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/votes/) that I used successfully, but on less complicated data format, and I can't make it works now. Here it is.

```
client.collection('games').update({_id: gameId, 'proposals.id': eventId, 'proposals.voters': {'$ne': user}}, {'$push': {'proposals.voters': user}, '$inc': {'proposals.vote_count': 1}, '$set': {'proposals.validate': 1}});
```

gameId and eventId are in the right format. If I use the query part of the update in a find(), I get the right game. But I'm struggling to see why my document isn't updated.

Comment: i think proposals.voter value is user..thats y its not working because of this code -'proposals.voters': {'$ne': user}}

Comment: It was indeed a part of the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must you [$ operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/#op._S_) to identify what position in array you want update. Your update command will be:

```
client.collection('games')
.update( 
    {
        _id: gameId, 
        'proposals.id': eventId, 
        'proposals.voters': {'$ne': user}
    }, 
    {
        '$push': {'proposals.$.voters': user},
        '$inc': {'proposals.$.vote_count': vote}, 
        '$set': {'proposals.$.validate': 1}
    }
);
```

Comment: Well, I don't understand. I change my request, tried it, it worked. Retried it, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: There's none. It just doesn't update. That's weird, considering it worked the first time.

Comment: I tested the update query multiple times and work properly. Check if your find query is correct.

Comment: It was missing a $ between proposals and voters in the find query. I don't understand why it worked the first time. Thanks a lot !